# Stop command prompt from opening when running compiled .exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, command-prompt

When I build, compile and run my Visual Studio project, a command prompt also opens with the window.  It does this with the compiled .exes as well as in the dev environment.  Is there a way to stop the command prompt from opening for the compiled .exes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can switch the subsystem in the linker settings from "CONSOLE" to "WINDOWS", which will stop the OS from creating an initial console window for the process. It can still create one afterwards though, in which case you'd have to modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching compilation mode to 'Release'. Change build target to another than console (depends on your current project, for example Win32 Application).